# Use sqlite3 to import ASCII text file to Firefox cookies.sqlite

Tags: sqlite, firefox, cookies, import

I would like to edit Firefox cookies using Bash on OS X. I can use the following to convert cookies.sqlite to an ASCII text file:

```
cd ~/Library/Firefox; sqlite3 cookies.sqlite .dump > test
```

However I have not yet found a way to convert an edited ASCII text file back to cookies.sqlite. I have tried both dump import and CSV import - sections 8 and 10 on https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

I suspect the main problem is the format of cookies.sqlite. The following is an example ASCII dump:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE moz_cookies (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, baseDomain TEXT, originAttributes TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', name TEXT, value TEXT, host TEXT, path TEXT, expiry INTEGER, lastAccessed INTEGER, creationTime INTEGER, isSecure INTEGER, isHttpOnly INTEGER, appId INTEGER DEFAULT 0, inBrowserElement INTEGER DEFAULT 0, CONSTRAINT moz_uniqueid UNIQUE (name, host, path, originAttributes));
INSERT INTO moz_cookies VALUES(33,'google.com','','CONSENT','WP.27b523','.google.com','/',2145916800,1561389135468630,1561365552747342,0,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO moz_cookies VALUES(115,'stackoverflow.com','','_gat','1','.stackoverflow.com','/',1561389104,1561389044656946,1561389044656946,0,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO moz_cookies VALUES(117,'stackoverflow.com','','usr','p=[2|6]','stackoverflow.com','/',1577200300,1561389100380300,1561389043655888,1,1,0,0);
INSERT INTO moz_cookies VALUES(120,'google.com','','1P_JAR','2019-06-24-15','.google.com','/',1563981135,1561389135573521,1561365552746756,0,0,0,0);
CREATE INDEX moz_basedomain ON moz_cookies (baseDomain, originAttributes);
COMMIT;
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just redirect the file to `sqlite3`'s standard input:

```
sqlite3 cookies.sqlite < test
```

You'll want to drop existing tables first to avoid all sorts of problems with duplicates though.

Another alternative is to use `.read FILENAME` from in the sqlite shell.

Comment: Many thanks - works well with this test: cd ~/Library/Firefox; c=cookies.sqlite; sqlite3 $c .dump > y; rm $c; sqlite3 $c < y;